# ASP.NET Core - posting form data to controller using ajax. One method works, one does not. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am posting data from a view, in simple HTML form

```
<form id="notificationForm" method="post">
```

Then, I am sending the form data to a controller (simplified example):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateNotification(LenderNotificationEvent model)
{
   return Json("Ok");
}
```

I have tried 2 ways to get the form data to a model in the controller.
This does not work:

```
$("#notificationForm").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: "/Lender/UpdateNotification",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $("#notificationForm").serialize(),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      });

      jqxhr.done(function (data) {
      });

      jqxhr.fail(function () {
      });
    
});
```

This does work:

```
$("#notificationForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('/Lender/UpdateNotification', $('#notificationForm').serialize(), function () {
});
```

Why? I don't understand how they are different.

EDIT:
What I mean by "not working", the model is null when I use $.ajax and the model is filled with data using $.post.
The controller gets hit by both methods.

EDIT 2:
I have stepped through the code, I do not get errors, and when I use $.ajax the model object in the controller is empty, and when I use $.post, the model object in the controller is filled with expected data.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you not hit the controller? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen at all? Have you stepped through your code? Please be clearer.

Comment: Hi DavidG. Thanks for commenting. I have added more detail to my post.

Comment: I have stepped through the code, I do not get errors, and when I use $.ajax the model object in the controller is empty, and when I use $.post, the model object in the controller is filled with expected data.

Comment: data: $("#notificationForm) Seems to be missing a closing double quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have a typo in the `$.ajax()` code:

```js
  data: $("#notificationForm).serialize(),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

It's actually missing a double quote in form id, so it should be:

```js
  data: $("#notificationForm").serialize(),
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
});
```

**Update:**
After fixing the typo try setting the `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`

Comment: Thanks Fadi. They typo was super dumb but fixing it did not change the outcome as detailed in my post

Comment: Thought that might be the issue, I'll review again and see how that could be fixed

Comment: I've updated my answer with suggested solution, let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: The update should fix this. Also note that you can remove `contentType` entirely and it'll also work.

Comment: Thank you Fadi, and Kirk. Changing the content type worked.
Is the content type in my case defaulted to form-urlencoded because I serialized form data?